# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS not working in fullscreen, lagging video, freezing after to the lastest update

Tags: wireless, video, shutdown, fullscreen

i'm new in ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS there are three questions

1. after update to the lastest ver, my fullscreen it's not working properly it's like lagging but the icons will show i'm moving my cursor in the window, it's like the image below

[not working fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFHbk.jpg)

2. everytime i'm changing my wifi connection, my laptop is freezin (stop working)
3. everytime i'm playing video, the video is lagging and my laptop won't shutdown (poweroff)

[the info on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW6po.jpg)

i need to fix this asap because i'm using this laptop to do my final project thesis, any advice will apprreciated

Comment: If you can through the GRUB menu, select Advanced and choose the next newest Kernel.  Not sure what update(s) might have caused this type of behavior to happen, but you can try the Kernel just before to see if it is a Kernel issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But it's happen in advance mode, in normal mode the full screen works normal but freezing when playing video and won't power off. Now i'm confused